# Dual Monitor resolution doesn't work.

Tags: dual-boot, ati, xorg, resolution

So here's the thing, you are my last resort, I have tried a lot of things before asking you for help, well not a lot, just two I think but I don't know that much so it's hard for me to change anything.

My problem is the following, I have two monitors, I just switched from windows 7 to ubuntu, to try new things, and I LOVE IT, but there's a problem that just buggs me.

I have two monitors one is connected via **HDMI** and the other one is connected via **a vga to dvi adapter**, both are 21.5" and support 1920x1080, the problem is this:

The first monitor (HDM) works just fine, got it to full res, no problem.
The second monitor says that it supports only 1600x1200 res, which my monitor only supports 1080 so it doesn't run on it, but it runs just fine on 1600x900, this is how it looks like - http://i5.minus.com/i17vJ3iqylDvZ.png

I have tried to manually alter the resolution in xorg.conf but it did not work, it returned back to 1600x900.

This bugs me a lot, I have got used to dual monitors from using them a long time, and I want to do it again on ubuntu but I don't know how. So please, help me, I am really in need of help.

I am using the latest drivers from the amd website (not the beta) for my card. I have a ATI RADEON HD 7950 3GB 384 bytes GDDR5.

This is my current xorg.conf http://pastebin.com/xcF7kms6 , I am using the latest version of ubuntu, all updates done.

You are literally my last resort, please help me get this thing sorted. Thank you.

Comment: Is it at all possible to connect your monitor without the VGA-DVI connector? It's possible that that is messing with the communication between the computer and the monitor.

Comment: Very likely to be the converter. I saw this happen to somebody on IRC the other day. The fix is to write the monitor refresh rates in xorg.conf.